# firefox custom video controllers do not show

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I`m having an issue with my custom video controller.
When the video is opened in firefox the controllers do not show in fullscreen mode.
I tried everything i found in regards to the topic, but no luck so far.
Here is the html:

```
<div id="contentContainer" class="border">
<div id="videoStreamed">    
    <video autoplay="" name="media" src="blob:https://****/f3213f7c-2955-46f6-94d5-e737dc8d619e" title="Customer Centricity" width="100%" height="100%">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
<div id="videoController">
    <div id="videoProgress">
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <div id="progress-fill-video" style="width: 7.77856%;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="playOrPause" class="controllerTabs"><i class="activeController icon-pause"></i></div>
    <div id="volume" class="controllerTabs"><i class="activeController icon-mute"></i></div>
    <div id="subs" class="controllerTabs"><i class="icon-sub inactiveController"></i></div>
    <div id="duration">
        <span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">12</span>
        <span id="total">/ 02:39</span>
    </div>
    <div id="download" class="controllerTabs"><i class=" icon-download inactiveController"></i></div>
    <div id="trascript" class="controllerTabs"><i class=" icon-transcript inactiveController"></i></div>
    <div id="fullScreen" class="controllerTabs"><i class=" icon-fullscreen activeController"></i></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the css :

```
#videoStreamed {
    position: relative;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1 !important;}
```

the video itself has the same z-index;

```
#videoController {
    z-index: 2147483647;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: From where is the fullScreen mode called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a wild guess since you didn't shown any js, but I will assume you called [`Element.requestFullscreen()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) on your video.

While it works in other browsers, in FF, this will exclude all non descendants of the `element` on which you called it from being displayed in the fullscreen mode.

I left taking news of the fullscreen API a long time ago, since it was a mess, but at this time specs weren't clear on what should be the correct behavior.

Nevertheless, one thing that works for every browser is to wrap both your video and your controls inside a single container and call `requestFullscreen` on this container.

Then you will need to style all your elements accordingly in the fullscreen mode with the [`:fullscreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) pseudo-class.

---

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ytsmwpv/) since stacksnippets don't allow fullscreen.

---

Sounds easy said like that? Well what I omitted is that still today, all browsers don't have a stable version of this API and that you will have to repeat your code like 5 times to deal with vendor-specifics quirks...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! You just saved my day!!!